# WSO2 guaranteed delivery message In memory store

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Trying to make workable solution for guaranteed delivery In memory.

Create InMemoryStore **InMemMessageStore**, create and point **InsertInvoice**
create API so code looking like this :

Sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <sequence name="InMMSsequence" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="STATE" value="message is sent to InMemMessageStore"/>
    </log>
    <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="True"/>
    <axis2ns12:store messageStore="InMemMessageStore" xmlns:axis2ns12="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/> </sequence>
```

my API looks like :

```
 <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/sendMessage">
      <inSequence>
         <sequence key="InMMSsequence"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
```

Message Processor :

```
<messageProcessor name="MySMessageProcessor" class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor" targetEndpoint="InsertInvoice" messageStore="InMemMessageStore" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
   <parameter name="client.retry.interval">1000</parameter>
   <parameter name="max.delivery.attempts">4</parameter>
   <parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="max.delivery.drop">Disabled</parameter>
   <parameter name="member.count">1</parameter>
</messageProcessor>
```

And point :

```
   <endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
    name="InsertInvoice">    
<http  uri-template="http://xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/InsertInvoiceVehicleList"
    method="post">
           <suspendOnFailure>
              <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
           </suspendOnFailure>
           <markForSuspension>
              <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
              <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
           </markForSuspension>    </http> </endpoint>
```

PROBLEMS:

1. over PostMan I'm sending the request in JSON format but when I open InMemMessageStore message is in XML ?!? Why?
2. Endpoint expecting message in JSON format. Probably this is the reason of failure BUT on log I see something like

**Failed to send the message through the fault sequence. Sequence name does not Exist.**

Is the fault sequence mandatory or it is complaining because I don't have any default error sequence defines at all ?

also

Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/InsertInvoiceVehicleList/**sendMessage**]

Why the **'sendMessage'** (This is uritemplate that is defined in API is added on endpoint url ?!?!)

so : Biggest issue here is how to keep message in JSON format and how to keep endpoint url intact  ...

Comment: Regarding #1: Try to print the content-type header in the input sequence, just to check its type prior being stored. My guess is that you´re just seeing a XML representation of the internal message,  not the actual one that is sent to the backend.
Regarding #2: If your endpoint returns some sort of response, you need to specify a sequence that will consume this content. This sequence can simply drop the message.

Comment: #1: I added <property expression="get-property('transport', 'Content-Type')"
        name="ctype" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('ctype')" name="ctype_id" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        <property name="STATE" value="message is SENT to InMessageStore "/>
    </log> and responce was ctype_id = application/json, STATE = message is SENT to InMessageStore - I hope that this prof your theory BUT In memory I still see it as XML.... and for 2# I dont get it ..

Comment: Also the BIG problem is when processor get message from store and send it to endpoint it adds uriTemplate form API on end?!? That cause that url is not the correct one ...Can you explain that or fix it ?

Comment: Regarding #2: The message processor takes a message out of the store and sends it to the defined endpoint. If there is any kind of response, Synapse must send it somewhere, hence the need for a response and, optionally a fault sequence. As for the "big" problem: I suggest you to change from a Scheduled processor to a Sampling processor with a target sequence responsible to make the actual call. The "sendMessage" that´s being added to the URI seems very strange, indeed. Can you confirm that it is actually being sent over the wire using backend´s logs or something like that ?

Comment: I found that '<property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>' removes "**sendMessage**" that´s being added to the URI ...but now my BIG problem is that processor sending message to sequence that call endpoint with no issues at all , BUT when processor send message directly to end point it's failing

Comment: Good catch on the REST_URL_POSTFIX. I didn´t pay attention to your API definition. The "uri-template" in this case is saved in the axis context and ends up added to the final address URL. Can you post some additional details on the error you´re getting ? Can you monitor your backend in order to check if the ESB sends anything to it ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and I wanted to share it with others ...

**1. call end point from API adds postfix on end gives the error**

By default, URI template 'sendMessage' will get appended to the target URL when sending messages out. You need to use following property in your sequence to remove URI template from target URL

```
<property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>.
```

**2. message processor fails to send message to end point**

My end point was api .net web service and issue was with HTTP 1.1 chunking,had to disable it since .NET service doesn’t support it.
This setting is in axis2_blocking_client.xml and axis2_client.xml

```
    <parameter name="Transfer-Encoding">chunked</parameter>
```

**3. message processor fails to send message to end point**

my seccond End point was servicestack web service and I used end point like

```
http://xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/TMSALSvc/UpdateStatus
```

but problem was that I needed to specify the reponce format. Once when I put a EndPoint delaration like

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/TMSALSvc/json/reply/UpdateStatus
```

everything forked

I hope that this can same some times for other facing the same issues